# how to extract only first two characters with imacro?

Tags: imacros

So the HTML code is :

```
    <span class="countdown">
    01:22
    </span>
```

The imacro code to extract the text (01:22) is :

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:"countdown" EXTRACT=TXT
```

I want to extract only the first two characters and not the whole text, in the example i posted , the extracted TEXT would be "01" and not "01:22"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the imacro EVAL method and use a little bit of javascript and regex to break up the string and assign it to another variable so that you get the first 2 characters.  Below is the solution:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:"countdown" EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var x=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; x=x.match(/^.{2}/).join(''); x;")
PROMPT {{!VAR1}}
```

Enjoy!  If this was helpful, please mark as such, thanks!

*Edit* Here's a slightly better method, using the javascript split function.  This will allow you to specify the 1st part (`01`) or the 2nd part (`22`) of `01:22`

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:"countdown" EXTRACT=TXT
' Below line will assign the first part before colon (01) to VAR1
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var x=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; y=x.join(':'); y[0];")
' Below line will assign the first part before colon (01) to VAR2
SET !VAR2 EVAL("var x=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; x=x.join(':'); y[1];")
PROMPT {{!VAR1}}
```

Answer updated due to recent comment/question to my answer.

Comment: and how do you extract characters from second position?

Comment: I've updated the answer to address your question/comment.  Basically, use the JS split function to separate the string into an array, and then you can select which side to use (hours or minutes).